# How to bind to a property on a gridviewcolumn from its celltemplate

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, gridviewcolumn

The general problem I want to solve is to have just one datatemplate for a checkbox which I can then use for many different columns in a listview (using a gridview). In all examples I've seen a seperate template is created for each binding which seems overkill to me.

I've been trying to do this by creating an attached property that the gridviewcolumn will set. Then I can simply have one datatemplate for a checkbox that binds to that attached property.

The problem I'm having is actually setting the checkbox source to the gridviewcolumn.

Here is the xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxTemplate">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=(ap:AttachedProperties.IsChecked),
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}}}" />
</DataTemplate>

<GridView x:Key="MyGridView">
    <GridViewColumn Header="CheckBox" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxTemplate}" ap:AttachedProperties.IsChecked="{Binding Path=SomeValue}" />
</GridView>
```

*P.S. The Attached property is working fine, I've attached it directly to the checkbox and used a relativesource self binding and gotten the values coming through, but when I try to bind it on the GridViewColumn I get no happiness, in fact I haven't been able to bind to the Header on the GridViewColumn either...*

*P.P.S I have tried other binding source expressions as well (just not the right one it seems)...*

Edit:
Immediately after posting this it dawned on me that the GridViewColumn exists for all rows and so that is probably why this isn't working?!

I've slept on it now and realise that doing things in this way wont work (because the GridViewColumn can only hold the value for the first row not each row as I would need it to) - however I still would have thought it possible to bind to the GridViewColumn?

Here is a xaml only example to show the behaviour:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="MainWindow"
       Width="525"
       Height="350">
   <Grid>
       <ListView Name="listView1"
                 Width="479"
                 Height="287"
                 Margin="12,12,0,0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top">
           <ListView.View>
               <GridView>
                   <GridViewColumn Header="A Header">
                       <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                               <StackPanel>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}}}" />
                                   <TextBlock Text="Visible row" />
                               </StackPanel>
                           </DataTemplate>
                       </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                   </GridViewColumn>
               </GridView>
           </ListView.View>
           <ListViewItem />
           <ListViewItem />
       </ListView>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Under such a scenerio I would expect to see "A Header" just above each "Visible row" text

Comment: How is your attach property defined? What is it's callback? How is it bubbling up to the parent control (GridViewColumn)?

Comment: The attached property is working (the same problem applies if I simply bind a textblock to the header of the gridviewcolumn). I've had a chance to sleep on it and realise that binding to the gridviewcolumn in this way wont achieve what I want - but I still would expect it to be possible but can't see how

Comment: This is Windows 8 you are talking about not WPF, right? So according to you your attach property on the checkbox is working fine, have you tried something like this <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=(ap:AttachedProperties.IsChecked),
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type GridViewColumn}}, Mode=TwoWay}" />

Comment: I want to clarify that your grid view rows would have more than one check box in it? And how would you want it to behave? I'm sorry I'm trying to reproduce your problem.

Comment: No this is windows 7. wpf in .Net 4. I've prepared a simplified xaml only example to illustrate the behaviour, and will post that into the main question

Comment: I've snooped it and seen that GridViewColumn doesn't appear in the visultree, I don't fully understand this; but I would take that to be the underlying reason I can't bind to it... I would put that as the answer and finalise this question but would rather get confirmation from someone who is more sure about such things as I'm still quite new to wpf/c#.

Comment: I gave you the answer which is straight forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've check snoop, the reason why that is not working because GridColumnHeader is not in the VisualTree where the GridRows are. My solution is to use ElementName and bind it to the Header property. Fairly simple, much cleaner and readable.

```
    <ListView Name="listView1"
             Width="479"
             Height="287"
             Margin="12,12,0,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="A Header" x:Name="HeaderOne">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=HeaderOne,Path=Header}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="Visible row" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem />
        <ListViewItem />
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this - I like the idea of using an element name; unfortunately this doesn't seem to work when the datatemplate is split out and used as a staticresource.

Comment: No, that doesn't make any difference. It will still look for the element name in the VisualTree even if it the DataTemplate is used as a StaticResource. Please mark my answer if it did help. Thanks!

Comment: I found why using the elementname wasn't working for me; if the datatemplate and gridview are broken out and put in a resourcedictionary (as I had been doing) then it doesn't work, but copy and paste it directly to the resources section of the window and it does work... I couldn't find anything concrete which explained that behaviour, but that is a seperate issue to my question.

Answer (score 2):

My problem of trying to bind to the GridViewColumn appears to be two-fold:

- Firstly the GridViewColumn can only provide one resultant value (probably the first item in the itemssource) as opposed to a value on a per row basis.
- Secondly the GridViewColumn does not appear to exist in the visualtree and so is not available for binding to.

Further research shows that to bind to properties of the GridViewColumn, the following syntax can be used:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=View.Columns[0].Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" />
```

Obtained from [MSDN: Passing a parameter into a CellTemplate specified in a GridViewColumn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9ea2853c-dd21-49d8-95e8-a145d706a7f8/)